# Did the Gamecube's version of Legend of Zelda:Four Swords include the GBA link cable?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, game-boy, zelda-four-swords-adventures

I read on some strategy guides that the game boy controller cable for Gamecube was included on copies of the four sword game. But I can't find that information anywhere else. None of the copies still sold on Amazon and overseas and the old ads I could find mention it.

Did it really? Or was it only sold as an accessory?

Comment: It also came bundled with the Gamecube at some point. I had one that I got that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Legend of Zelda: Four Swords Adventures (Link Cable Bundle Edition)**

I found related images on [this post on CollectionStation](http://www.collectionstation.com/collectibles/4873-The-Legend-of-Zelda:-Four-Swords-Adventures-Link-Cable-Bundle-Edition-):

[image]
[image]

Note the larger box that advertises the bundled cable. The second image details everything that came with the bundle.

Comment: awesome site. too bad the images are such low quality... thanks for the great answer